# how to show more than one item with SelectList (it's a dropdown) , im using mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, selectlist

this is my code:

```
ViewBag.idprofesor = new SelectList(db.Profesor, "IDProfesor", "nombre");
```

this code generate a dropdown that only shows the name (nombre) of the teachers (profesor) in the database, id like the dropdown to show the name and the lastname of the teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to manually create a ist of SelectListItems that manually specify the fields you want. Like so:

```
List<SelectListItem> professors = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var professor in db.Professors) {
    professors.Add( new SelectListItem() { Text = professor.Fn + " " +  professor.Ln, Value = professor.Id } );
}
ViewVag.Professors = professors;
```

Then in your view:

```
Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.Professor, ViewBag.Professors );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have a problem with the view part...
@Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.Professor, ViewBag.Professors );
this code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass an IEnumerable of *SelectListItem* to the constructor.  Using Linq to select from the *Professor* collection:

```
@{
    var mySelectList =
        db.Professor.Select(prof => new SelectListItem(
            Text = prof.lastName + ", " + prof.nombre,
            Value = prof.IDProfessor
            )
        ).AsEnumerable();
}
```

Using Razor, you should be able to create the drop down list like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("mydropdownlist", mySelectList)
```

To bind it to a property in your model, the syntax is slightly different:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.someproperty, mySelectList)
```

Comment: what should i put in the "view" part??

Comment: @user1462933 are you using Razor or ASPX syntax in your views?  If Razor, please see my update (I noticed there were a few syntax errors).

Comment: yes, im using razor.. but that still does not work.. when i put this: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.idprofesor, ViewBag.SelectListItems) i got an error that says : Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched...

Comment: @user1462933 try declaring the items as *mySelectList* at the top of the Razor page (updated my answer).